# Javascript Promise - wait for .then() to execute before resolving?

Tags: javascript, promise

So, we have something like this:

```js
function thePromise(){
 var thePromise = new Promise(function(){
        var data = 'foo';
        console.log(data);
        resolve();
    });
 return thePromise;
}

thePromise().then( function(){
console.log('bar');
});
console.log('foobar');
```

One would expect that the order of output would be `foo, bar, foobar`, but it always ends up being `foo, foobar, bar`.

Is there a way, aside from using `setTimeout()`, to ensure that the code inside the`.then()` is done before the next line of code is executed? I'm trying to do something with database manipulation and syncing with a remote server, so using `setTimeout()` is a risky proposition, because it can take a non-definite amount of time to resolve.

Comment: Some potentially useful reading: https://javascript.info/promise-chaining

Comment: Also await https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

Comment: `fctn;` does not call the function, and your initial Promise callback never calls `resolve()`. That code would never print "bar" on the console.

Comment: @Will Cain Unfortunately, I'm using something that doesn't have the ability to use async/await.

Comment: Yeah, your example and what you're saying is happening doesn't work. In fact, it's bogus code. Converted into a snippet. Go ahead and [edit] it to update its behavior so that it matches what your real code is doing.

Comment: This is actually one of the main points of promises - they are guaranteed to resolve asynchronously, so your code always flows the same way (`foobar` before `bar`).

Comment: so why are you not putting the logic in the `then` ? You need to change the code in order for it to work, that is how asynchronous code runs.

Comment: I'm working on it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply chain your promises  :

```js
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    resolve(console.log('foo'));
});
var fctn = function(){
   console.log('bar');
}

promise.then(fctn).then(function(){
  console.log('foobar');
});
```

Comment: Or more compactly `new Promise(function(resolve){ resolve(console.log('foo')); }).then(function(){ console.log('bar'); }).then(function(){ console.log('foobar'); });`

Answer (score 0):

then() returns a Promise, so you can chain:

```
thePromise().then( function(){
   console.log('bar');
})
.then(function() { 
    console.log('foobar'); 
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like

```
(fctn).then((response) => {
  //Your Logic
}
```

As described in [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) (in case you're using angular)

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm using Titanium.